# How to echo a specific value from an array in php using REST API , need to echo name from the given array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [root] => Array
        (
            [status] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [message] => OK
                )

            [response] => Array
                (
                    [success] => 1
                    [result] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [content] => 12
                                    [enabled] => 1
                                    [date_modified] => 2013-03-07 19:28:19
                                    [name] => Home page
                                    [category_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [error_messages] => 
                    [debug] =>
```

Please help me to echo the name from the given array. i have tried many things but not able to find correct , please help me on it.

Comment: Where does the REST API come into play?

Comment: You should be more specific on what are you asking.

Comment: @knittl-I am new to REST API,i am trying to learn how to do php in  Restapi..

Comment: @axierjhtjz-I am not familiar with doing php in the Restapi framework i am having..thats why i got stuck and was not able to print the array value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you're going to get more than one name, so:

```
foreach($yourArrayRef['root']['response']['result'] as $result) {
   echo $result['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr['response']['result'][0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $response["result"][0]["name"];
```